# WPF DataGrid Header styling

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, expression-blend, blend

I want to create a custom styled header for WPF DataGrid, but I don't know if it is possible to do what I want, and if it is how exactly should I do.

The sketch of the DataGrid is on the linked picture. The Purple header extends beyond the edge of the DataGrid and it has a little 3D bending.

[DataGrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZtoJ.jpg)

Can I do something like this with WPF DataGrind and if yes how do I start?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

DataGrid allows for ColumnHeaderStyle, CellStyle and many more styles to bet set. Right click DataGrid control in designer view > View Additional Templates will show you the complete list.

You have to use the following :

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 3 0"/>
</Style>
```

This will change the column headers. And if you want to change cells too, you can provide styles for DataGridCell too.

Use Snoop tool to peek inside a DataGrid first and peek into it to see what it looks like at runtime. This will clear many of your concepts.

Comment: Great answer. I did not know yet that the context menu can create templates. The generated template gives a good starting point for own modifications.

Comment: @Martin Ask this question separately, I will try to answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but it is a **lot** of work and requires very good knowledge of writing WPF templates. What you essentially want to do is replace the templates for DataGrid, **and all other DataGrid related conotrols such as the DataGridRow, etc**

Microsoft provide a full example of how to do this here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff506248(v=vs.100).aspx